# How to distinguish "wherefore" from "therefore"

Tags: meaning, etymology, word-usage, semantics

I'm aware that the word "wherefore" can be used in the same way as "why", as in classic Shakespeare: "Wherefore art thou Romeo" (NOT meaning where).

However how else can it be properly used? Please don't just give me a dictionary definition, or a simple example, but please help distinguish it from "therefore", which is the thrust of my question.

Cheers.

Comment: Have you looked in dictionaries to see examples of its usage/s?

Comment: I have @EdwinAshworth, they usually give me the definition closest to "why", and, when supplying the other, aren't, in my mind, distinguishing it well enough from "therefore"...

Comment: I suggest you make a question more focused on what you don't understand (your doubts ) about its usage that cannot be found in dictionaries, or it may be seen as a GR question.

Comment: I said examples. Not definitions. eg Oxford Dictionaries has: Definition of wherefore in English:
interrogative adverb

**For what reason**:
_she took an ill turn, but wherefore I cannot say_ // 
relative adverb& conjunction

**As a result of which**:
[AS CONJUNCTION]: _truly he cared for me, wherefore I title him with all respect_
MORE EXAMPLE SENTENCES

Comment: Only lawyers should use this word. It's not part of standard modern English, and only exists in formulaic speech and writing.

Comment: @ John Samps: ... _aren't, in my mind, distinguishing it well enough from "therefore_.. But if _wherefore_ prefaces a question ("why?"), _therefore_ resolves the answer: ("so... ") .

Comment: @Josh61 I'll should have clarified by asking if it can be used interchangeably with "therefore" (which in all cases I don't think it can).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth in that example you've just provided I see little difference between "therefore" and "wherefore" which goes back to my original comment.

Comment: Thank you @Margana for helping distinguish between "therefore" and "wherefore"

Comment: I quoted _two_ example sentences. If you look at the site guidelines, you'll see that finding and posting such things (when they're easy to find, as here) is the job of the person asking the question.

Answer (score 4):

The Book of Common Prayer uses **wherefore** as a resumptive (relative conjunction). After the minister has read the preface explaining why confession is appropriate he/she starts the next paragraph:

> **Wherefore** I pray and beseech you, as many as are here present, to accompany me...

For which reason...

Answer (score 1):

**The OED provides six different senses, with examples from the 13th century onward**. This is the list of senses, and I have given the most recent examples of each.

> **I. Interrogative uses.**
>   For the dependent or indirect interrogative use, and its distinction from the relative, cf. what pron., adj.1, and adv. I.
>
> 1. *For what? esp. for what purpose or end? (Often scarcely distinguishable from 2.)*
>
> > a1616  Shakespeare *Comedy of Errors* (1623) iii. i. 40 E.  *Ant.*.. Open the dore. *S. Dro.* Right sir, Ile tell you when, and you'll tell me wherefore. *Ant.* Wherefore? for my dinner.
> >
> > 1667  Milton *Paradise Lost* iv. 657  But wherfore all night long shine these..?
> >
> > 1846  A. Marsh *Father Darcy* xxix,  Here I am—wherefore come, I have to learn.
>
> 2. *For what cause or reason? on what account? why? (Freq. with ellipsis; often coupled with why for emphasis.)*
>
> > 1853  Dickens *Bleak House* xx. 193  If he be ever asked how, why, when, or wherefore, he shuts up one eye and shakes his head.
> >
> > 1873  H. W. Longfellow *Michael Angelo* i. iv,  But wherefore should I jest?
>
> **II. Relative uses.**
>
> 3. *For which. Now distinguished by stress and spelling (whereˈfor).*
>
> > 1600  Shakespeare *Henry V* v. ii. 1  Peace to this meeting, wherefore we are met.
> >
> > 1913  *Act 3 & 4 Geo. V* c. 20 §118 (1) (d)  All sums (not exceeding..one hundred pounds) due in respect of compensation under the Workmen's Compensation Act, 1906, the liability wherefor accrued before the said date.
>
> 4. *On account of or because of which; in consequence or as a result of which. Chiefly with n. (esp. reason or cause) as antecedent.* arch.
>
> > 1597  R. Hooker *Of Lawes Eccl. Politie* v. lxiii. 151  The true reason wherfore Christ doth loue belieuers is because their belief is the gift of God.
> >
> > 1829  R. Southey *Sir T. More* II. 187  The reason is sufficiently manifest wherefore a preference for republican institutions should hitherto have been shown.
>
> 5. a. *Introducing a clause expressing a consequence or inference from what has just been stated: On which account; for which reason; which being the case; and therefore. (Now always ˈwherefore.)*

1842   Tennyson Morte d'Arthur in Poems (new ed.) II. 15   More things are wrought by prayer Than this world dreams of. Wherefore, let thy voice Rise like a fountain for me night and day.

1882   W. Besant All Sorts of Men II. xxix. 238   A person, you see, is an individual, or an indivisible thing. Wherefore, let us not despise our neighbour.

5b  - obsolete

> > **III.**
>
> 6. as n. *A question beginning with wherefore, or (more usually) the answer to such question; cause, reason. Often following why similarly used.*
>
> > 1838  Dickens *Oliver Twist* II. xxx. 184  They will have the why and the wherefore, and take nothing for granted.
> >
> > 1884  A. S. Swan *Dorothea Kirke* xiv,  I am carried back to the days when I rebelled and demanded the wherefore of all God's dealings with me.

Comment: This is just copy paste from the OED. Can you at least add some minimal meaningful commentary to address the OPs concerns?

Comment: @Mitch The OP seemed to want examples - so that is what I gave. But thanks to Janus.

Comment: Thank you @WS2, I suppose my original question should be rephrased, asking how this word ought to be distinguished from "therefore"

Comment: @John Samps  Senses 4 and 5a would seem to have some correspondence with *therefore*. Otherwise it appears to me mainly interrogative.

Comment: John Lawler gave the (or at least _an_) answer to the most sensible interpretation of the original question, which was 'However how else **can** (not 'could') it be properly used?   _Only lawyers should use this word. It's not part of standard modern English, and only exists in formulaic speech and writing._  We really should start divorcing historical analyses from modern usage advice.